# Java calling C++ with JNI: why does the JNIEnv pointer get dereferenced twice?

Tags: c++

This code is copied directly from http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/objtypes.html#4013

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL 
Java_Prompt_getLine(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring prompt)
{
    char buf[128];
    const jbyte *str;
    str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, prompt, NULL);
    if (str == NULL) {
         return NULL; /* OutOfMemoryError already thrown */
    }
     printf("%s", str);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, prompt, str);
    /* We assume here that the user does not type more than
     * 127 characters */
    scanf("%s", buf);
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, buf);
}
```

Why is it neither

```
env->GetStringUTFChars(...
```

nor

```
(*env).GetStringUTFChars(...
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [earlier](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/objtypes.html#5190) in the document you linked in your question:

> The first parameter, the JNIEnv interface pointer, points to a location that contains a pointer to a function table

Reading this it seems that `JNIEnv` is itself a pointer. It's even a nice picture describing the relationships below the paragraph.

Comment: `JNIEnv` is a struct, not a pointer, as defined in java's infamous `jni.h` header file. The function is also inlined to allow programmers to write `env->GetStringUTFChars(...`. So both methods are correct.

Comment: Where do you get that from, that JNIEnv is a struct? In my `jni.h`, `JNIEnv` is a typedef for a _pointer to_ a `struct JNINativeInterface`. Given all JNI C API takes a `JNIEnv*`, this means it is really a `JNINativeInterface **`, meaning a pointer to a pointer of a struct. Which seems a bit unusual even for C code simulating virtual method dispatch using a function pointer table like `JNINativeInterface`.